# Mongoose - Query exec() never resolves in model method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, mongoose-schema

In an attempt to refactor some code that will be used in different places, I moved this method which was already working from a controller to a Mongoose model.

In the model, the `trackQuery.exec()` never reaches the callback, never resolves. If I resolve without the `exec()` or without waiting for the `exec()`, it works fine. The `trackQuery` is filled properly with a Mongoose `Query`.

What is the subtlety about Mongoose models that I don't get ?

```
ArtistSchema.methods.insertRelatedTracks = function (items) {
    const newTracksToSave = items.map((item) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const TrackModel = mongoose.model('Track'),
                trackQuery = TrackModel.findOne({ externalID: item.id })
            ;

            return trackQuery.exec((err, track) => {
                if (err) { 
                    return reject(err);
                }

                if (!track) {
                    let track = new TrackModel({
                        externalID: item.id,
                        provider: item.provider,
                        title: item.title,
                        artist: item.artist,
                        artistID: this._id,
                        artistExternalID: this.externalID,
                        thumbnail: item.thumbnail,
                        publishedAt: item.publishedAt,
                        count: 0
                    });

                    return track.save((err, res) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return reject(err);
                        }

                        return resolve(res);
                    });
                }

                return resolve(track);
            });
        });
    });

    return Promise.all(newTracksToSave).then(() => {
        return this;
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        return this;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was to manually import the `TrackModel` instead of relying on the usual runtime `mongoose.model('Track')` method. I have no explications why `mongoose.model` doesn't work in this case. Any hints are welcomed.

Comment: It's probably not related to your problem, but `.exec()` already returns a promise, so there's not need to wrap Mongoose queries with an extra `new Promise(...)`. One possible issue with your current code is that if a track doesn't exist, you still resolve the promise which an empty/undefined `track` variable, and it will resolve _before_ the call to `resolve(res)`. So the code should be `if (! track) { ... } else { return resolve(track) }`

Comment: @robertklep Thanks for your comment! :) It's definitely not related since the only difference in the code is the way to import the `TrackModel`. On the other hand, I was under the impression that Promises or not a `return` would stop the execution in the same scope. `return track.save...` would prevent ever reaching `return resolve(track);` if there is no track. Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I missed the `return` in front of `track.save()`. Please ignore that part of my comment ;D